# How to fix Indent error in pug with vue js

Tags: vue.js, pug

We have a whole network of projects, more than 15 projects, each of them has been working for more than three years. Today, suddenly after reinstalling node modules, an error appeared everywhere:

```
Syntax Error: Error: C:\Users\veneg\Desktop\***\assets2\src\views\template\Socials.vue:2:1
    1|
  > 2|   .social
-------^
    3|     a.social__link.rtl(v-for="(soc, index) in socials" :key="index" :href="soc.link" target="blank")
    4|       icon(:name="soc.name" nofill)
    5|

unexpected token "indent"
```

There are over 3000 files in the project with this error, how can I fix this?

I tried to play with pug loader versions but nothing helped.

My versions:

```
"vue-loader": "~15.6",
    "vue-style-loader": "~4.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "~2.6",
    "webpack": "~4.29",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "~3.0",
    "webpack-cli": "~3.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~3.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "~2.24",
    "webpack-merge": "~4.2"
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "4.4.1",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "5.0.2",
 "pug": "2.0.4",
    "pug-plain-loader": "1.0.0",
```

Comment: Had a quick search online and it doesn't look like vue eslint  supports pug. There's this package in alpha: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-vue-pug

Comment: Do you know why this happened? After all, eslint is not in the package.json dependencies. And I don't have his config at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `pug-plain-loader` try to use the [@webdiscus/pug-loader](https://github.com/webdiscus/pug-loader).

This loader support the indent in Vue template:

```html
<template lang='pug'>
    h1 Hello Pug!
    p Text
</template>
```

See [how to use Pug loader with Vue](https://github.com/webdiscus/pug-loader#usage-with-vue) and [source of example](https://github.com/webdiscus/pug-loader/tree/master/examples/hello-world-vue).

Comment: Then how it works more then 3 years before? and your example with error, pug must be a global wrap.

Comment: @EugenyVenegrad  Here is the indent issue by `pug-plain-loader` [Unexpected token "indent" on Vue 3 template ](https://github.com/yyx990803/pug-plain-loader/issues/18), since 2020.

Comment: @EugenyVenegrad "example with error" What do you mean?

Comment: pug template tags must be wrapped in global tag like a div, or u will get an error. just try run your code )

Comment: @EugenyVenegrad its work fine, w/o wrapping.

See the Vue source from working example:
https://github.com/webdiscus/pug-loader/blob/master/examples/hello-world-vue/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: its custom pug loader, with official is not working

Comment: `pug-plain-loader` is not official loader too.
The original pugjs/pug-loader is not maintained since 4 years, see https://github.com/pugjs/pug-loader/issues/124